# Ajuda em atividade de Algoritimos em C

Tags: c

Alguém sabe dizer o que estou fazendo de errado no meu código?

> 1) Faça um programa que determine a data cronologicamente maior entre duas datas fornecidas pelo usuário. Cada data deve ser composta por três valores inteiros, em que o primeiro representa o dia, o segundo, o mês e o terceiro, o ano.

Eis o que tentei:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h> //Biblioteca locale é uitlizada para definar o idioma do programa.

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese"); //Comando utilizado para caracteres especiais aparecerem.
    int dia,mes,ano;
    int dia2,mes2,ano2;

    printf("Comparador de datas \n\n");

    printf("Primeira data \n");
    printf("    Digite o dia (1 a 31): ");
    scanf("%d",&dia);
    printf("    Digite o mês (1 a 12): ");
    scanf("%d",&mes);
    printf("    Digite o ano: ");
    scanf("%d",&ano);

    printf("\n");

    printf("Segunda data \n");
    printf("    Digite o dia (1 a 31): ");
    scanf("%d",&dia2);
    printf("    Digite o mês (1 a 12): ");
    scanf("%d",&mes2);
    printf("    Digite o ano: ");
    scanf("%d",&ano2);

//Inicio compartivo de anos
    if (ano > ano2){
        printf("\n\n");
        printf("A maior data é %d/%d/%d \n",dia,mes,ano);
    }
    else if (ano2 > ano) {
        printf("\n\n");
        printf("A maior data é %d/%d/%d \n",dia2,mes2,ano2);
        printf("\n\n");
    }
//

//Inicio compartivo dos meses
    if (mes > mes2) {
        if (ano > ano2) {
            printf("\n\n");
            printf("A maior data é %d/%d/%d",dia,mes,ano);
            printf("\n\n");
        }
        else if( ano2 > ano); {
            printf("\n\n");
            printf("A maior data é %d/%d/%d",dia2,mes,ano2);
            printf("\n\n");
        }
    }

    else if (mes2 > mes) {
        if (ano > ano2) {
            printf("\n\n");
            printf("A maior data é %d/%d/%d",dia,mes,ano);
            printf("\n\n");

        }
        else if (ano2 > ano); {
            printf("\n\n");
            printf("A maior data é %d/%d/%d",dia2,mes2,ano2);
            printf("\n\n");

        }
    }
 //
 //Inicio compartivo dos dias
    if (dia > dia2) {
        if (ano > ano2) {
            printf("\n\n");
            printf("A maior data é %d/%d/%d",dia,mes,ano);
            printf("\n\n");
        }
        else if( ano2 > ano); {
            printf("\n\n");
            printf("A maior data é %d/%d/%d",dia,mes,ano2);
            printf("\n\n");
        }
    }

    else if (dia2 > dia) {
        if (ano > ano2) {
            printf("\n\n");
            printf("A maior data é %d/%d/%d",dia2,mes,ano);
            printf("\n\n");

        }
        else if (ano2 > ano); {
            printf("\n\n");
            printf("A maior data é %d/%d/%d",dia2,mes2,ano2);
            printf("\n\n");

        }
    }
}
```

[image: O resultado é o seguinte.]

Comment: é simples na verdade... você não esta terminando o programa após dar resposta.. e todos os blocos `if` estão sendo executados, logo para cada um deles uma resposta está sendo mostrada na tela. Além de você estar misturando as variáveis nos `printf`

Comment: uma outra maneira que você poderia verificar é simplesmente somando os valores `(ano + mes + dia)` e verificando qual é o maior.. isso simplificaria seu código para apenas um bloco `if`

Comment: Mds! É verdade,como não tinha pensado nisso,to a horas sofrendo com esse codigo.Muito obrigado  Irsael

Comment: A ideia do Israel é boa, porém se feita ingenuamente dar´pa problema. A soma deve ser feita considerando as grandezas de cada parte da data, o que é bem mais complicado do que parece por causa da irregularidade de datas., chegando ao ponto que acaba sendo mais simples converter para *string* e concatenar tudo, ainda que menos elegante e performático.

Comment: Claro que o código atual é ingênuo e aceita dias 29, 30 e 31 em meses que não tem essa quantidade de dias (bom, na prática, aceita até números completamente fora como milhões ou negativos). Se aceitar fazer errado pelo menos elimina a irregularidade, aí pode considerar o dia como unidade, o mês como dezena (multiplica por 31 nos meses completos, faz -1) e o ano seria como a centena (multiplica por 372 nos anos completos, portanto tem que fazer menos 1, obviamente que fica errado, mas a base já está errada). No fim ficaria complexo também, porque o problema é complexo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vejamos, em que condições a primeira data é maior?

> Se o ano da primeira data for maior que o da segunda. Ou então, se os anos forem iguais, se o mês da primeira data for maior do que o da segunda. Ou ainda, se os anos e meses das duas datas forem iguais, mas o dia da primeira for maior.

ou seja:

> `ano1 > ano2 || (ano1 == ano2 && mes1 > mes2) || (ano1 == ano2 && mes1 == mes2 && dia1 > dia2)`.

Isso ainda pode ser simplificado um pouco:

> `ano1 > ano2 || ano1 == ano2 && (mes1 > mes2 || (mes1 == mes2 && dia1 > dia2))`.

E para verificar se a segunda data é maior que a primeira ao invés do contrário, basta inverter os `>` para `<`.

Uma outra coisa é que você tem vários `if`s assim:

```
if (condicao) {
    comando1();
    comando2a();
    comando3();
} else {
    comando1();
    comando2b();
    comando3();
}
```

O `comando1()` e o `comando3()` são executados qualquer que seja o caminho tomado no `if`. Isso significa que podem ser movidos para fora dele:

```
comando1();
if (condicao) {
    comando2a();
} else {
    comando2b();
}
comando3();
```

Com isso, o seu código pode ser bastante simplificado:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h> //Biblioteca locale é uitlizada para definar o idioma do programa.

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese"); //Comando utilizado para caracteres especiais aparecerem.
    int dia1, mes1, ano1;
    int dia2, mes2, ano2;

    printf("Comparador de datas \n\n");

    printf("Primeira data \n");
    printf("    Digite o dia (1 a 31): ");
    scanf("%d", &dia1);
    printf("    Digite o mês (1 a 12): ");
    scanf("%d", &mes1);
    printf("    Digite o ano: ");
    scanf("%d", &ano1);

    printf("\n");

    printf("Segunda data \n");
    printf("    Digite o dia (1 a 31): ");
    scanf("%d", &dia2);
    printf("    Digite o mês (1 a 12): ");
    scanf("%d", &mes2);
    printf("    Digite o ano: ");
    scanf("%d", &ano2);

    // Compartivo
    printf("\n\n");
    if (ano1 > ano2 || ano1 == ano2 && (mes1 > mes2 || (mes1 == mes2 && dia1 > dia2))) {
        printf("A maior data é %d/%d/%d \n", dia1, mes1, ano1);
    } else if (ano1 < ano2 || ano1 == ano2 && (mes1 < mes2 || (mes1 == mes2 && dia1 < dia2))) {
        printf("A maior data é %d/%d/%d \n", dia2, mes2, ano2);
    } else {
        printf("As datas são iguais: %d/%d/%d \n", dia1, mes1, ano1);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/fVrSff)